# How do I know the confidence level of my correct probability score?

Tags: matlab, statistics, confidence-interval

I have a writer recognition system that gives back an NLL (Negative Least Likelihood) score for a test sample against every trained model. For example if there are thirteen models to compare the sample against the NLL output will look like this.

```
15885.1881156907    17948.1931699086    17205.1548161452    16846.8936368077    20798.8048757930    18153.8179076007    18972.6746781821    17398.9047592641    19292.8326540969    22559.3178790489    17315.0994094185    19471.9518308519    18867.2297851016
```

Where each column represents the score for that sample against every model. Column 1 gives the score against model 1 and so on.

This test sample is written by model 1. So the first column should have the minimum value for correct prediction.

The output I provided here gives the desired prediction, as the value of column 1 is minimum.

When I presented my results I was asked how confident I was about the scores or the predicted values? I was asked to provide a confidence level of each score.

I did some reading after this and found some posts on 95 % confidence interval which appears as every result to my google query but it does not appear to  be what I need.

The reason I need this is suppose for a test sample I have scores from 2 models. Then using the confidence level I am supposed to know which score to pick up.

For example for the same test sample the scores from another model are:

```
124494.535128967    129586.451168849    126269.733526396    129579.895935672    128582.387405272    125984.657455834    127486.755531507    125162.136816278    129790.811437270    135902.112799503    126599.346536290    136223.382395325    126182.202727967
```

Both are correctly predicting as in both cases score in column 1 is minimum. But again how do I find the confidence level of my score?

Would appreciate any guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my knowledge you cannot evaluate a confidence level for just one value.
Suppose you can store your results in a matrix where each column corresponds to a model and each row corresponds to an example (or *observation*). You can evaluate the confidence for every single model by using all the predicted results from that model (i.e. you can evaluate the confidence interval for any column in our matrix) according to the following procedure:

1. Evaluate the mean value of the column, let's call this *µ*
2. Evaluate the standard deviation of the column, let's call this *σ*
3. Evaluate the mean error as *ε=σ/sqrt(N)*, where *N* is the number of samples (rows)
4. the lower bound for the confidence interval is given by *µ-2ε* whereas the upper bound is given by *µ+2ε*. By straightforward subtraction you can find the amplitude of such confidence interval. The more is closer to zero, the more accurate is your measurement.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In some tests I do have more than one sample and the output is a matrix. But I do not understand your final step. What do you mean by subtraction amplitudes to get C.I.? Following your steps I have calculated the upper and lower bounds but what am I to subtract from to see if it is near zero or not.?

Comment: You do not subtract amplitudes, you subtract the upper and lower bounds. Let's say `Cup` is the upper bound and `Cdown` is the lower bound (evaluated as in step #4), by doing `Cup-Cdown` you get the amplitude of such interval, how large the gap is.